# Does $R$ being finitely generated imply all its ideals are finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So for my purposes $R$ is a commutative ring with identity. The question is, supposing that $R$ is finitely generated, meaning there is some finite subset $X = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\} \subseteq R$ for which $R = (X)$, do we get to conclude that every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated?

At first glance I thought this was yes, because if any ideal $I$ of $R$ is $I \subseteq (X)$ and so at least the finite set $X$ generates any ideal $I$. However, searching here I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128862/is-it-possible-that-a-finitely-generated-ring-has-an-ideal-that-is-not-finitely) which seems to indicate that this is equivalent to asking "are there non-Noetherian rings"; and I know they exist, but I don't see why this is the same. There's likely a stupid mistake I'm not seeing but what is the issue here.

**Edit:** Is the issue that $(X)$ is not necessarily a subset of $I$ itself, so it isn't a generating set? And a subset of $X$ might also not happen to be a subset of $I$? Why would this not be the case?

Comment: Every ring with identity is generated by $1$, if your notation is standard ( $(X)$ meaning the ideal generated by the subset $X$).  So they are all finitely generated in that sense.  A (commutative) Noetherian ring is one in which all ideals are finitely generated, so as you can see, if a nonnoetherian ring with identity exists, it is a counterexample to your question.

Comment: What about $R=(1)$?

Comment: @rschwieb I meant that I knew that non-Noetherian rings exist, I didn't see why asking if the implication $R$ finitely generated implies every ideal is finitely generated is equivalent to asking "do there exist non-noetherian rings exist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is equivalent to asking "are there non-Noetherian rings"; which is of course true, but I don't see why this is the same

A (commutative) Noetherian ring is one which all ideals are f.g.  Every (commutative with identity) is generated by $1$, and so $R$ is always finitely generated as an ideal. If it is to be Noetherian, the rest of the ideals have to be f.g. If there is one that isn't f.g., it must be a non-Noetherian ring.

So, you can see, if your conjecture that "$R$ f.g. implies all ideals of $R$ are f.g." were true it would entail that all commutative rings with identity are Noetherian.  This is of course not the case because non-Noetherian rings exist.

> Is the issue that $()$ is not necessarily a subset of $$ itself, so it isn't a generating set[?]

Yes, a generating set is necessarily a subset of the ideal it generates. Otherwise it generates things outside the ideal.

> And a subset of  might also not happen to be a subset of ? Why would this not be the case?

Well, look at the simplest case: $X=\{1\}$.  The identity is not contained in any proper ideal...

Comment: Yeah this cleared everything up, not great questions on my part. I appreciate the patience.

Comment: @IrvingRabin No problem. Thanks for helping me see what your difficulty was.